# How to scroll a div with a button using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a parent div with `overflow:hidden` that contains several children who are created dynamically. I want to be able to scroll the parent div with a button just like as if the div had `overflow-y:scroll`. The parent div always exposes 3 children at a time. How do I accomplish this with 2 buttons (scroll up and scroll down)? And yes it has to be with two buttons.

This is what I have so far

```js
var clicks = 300;
$('#parent').click(function(){
    $('#parent').scrollTo(clicks);
    clicks += 300;
    if(clicks>1200){
        clicks=0;
    }
});
```

```css
#parent { 
    width:200px; 
    height:300px; 
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:hidden;
}

.child {     
    width:200px; 
    height:100px;
    font-size:100px;
    text-align:center;
    color:black;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child" id="c1">1</div>
    <div class="child" id="c2">2</div>
    <div class="child" id="c3">3</div>
    <div class="child" id="c4">4</div>
    <div class="child" id="c5">5</div>
</div>

<button class="scroll-up">scroll up</button>
<button class="scroll-down">scroll down</button>
```

Comment: jQuery doesn't have a `scrollTo()` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need jQuery for this, so here's a vanilla JavaScript solution that doesn't even use an intermediary variable holding the scroll steps but instead just adds or removes the 300px from the current scroll position (the browser will prevent scrolling more than the scroll height or to a negative top value).

```js
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
document.querySelector('.scroll-up').addEventListener('click', function() {
  parent.scrollTo(0, parent.scrollTop - 300);
});
document.querySelector('.scroll-down').addEventListener('click', function() {
  parent.scrollTo(0, parent.scrollTop + 300);
});
```

```css
#parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.child {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child" id="c1">1</div>
  <div class="child" id="c2">2</div>
  <div class="child" id="c3">3</div>
  <div class="child" id="c4">4</div>
  <div class="child" id="c5">5</div>
</div>

<button class="scroll-up">scroll up</button>
<button class="scroll-down">scroll down</button>
```

---